# mapping json from a fetch function into setstate

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, mapping

I am trying to map a json response into a state, what I am trying to do is map all the children of this array no matter how many, as in skipping the first array and only show its children, here is what i tried to do

```
fetch(api).then((response) => {
  response.json()  .then((data) => {
    data.children.map( (menu) => {

      this.setState({
        mydata: menu
      })
}) console.log("test", this.state.mydata )})  
    });
```

this is what i receive from the api

```
  {
    "name": "Store 1",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Store 1",
        "children": [{},{}...]
      },
      {
        "name": "Store 2",
        "children": [{},{}...]
      }
    ]
  }
```

and this is how i want it stored in my state,

```
[
          {
            "name": "Store 1",
            "children": [{},{}...]
          },
          {
            "name": "Store 2",
            "children": [{},{}...]
          }
      ]
```

Comment: Invoking `this.setState()` in loop over the same `key` is the issue..

Comment: my goal is to have them mapped and stored to a state, instead of storing it and then mapping it in the render return

Comment: I would suggest mapping your array and then setting it in state once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's no need to map it. You should just put it into state.

```
fetch(api)
 .then(response => response.json())
 .then(data => this.setState({
  myData: data.children
 }))
```